# What CSS rules are introduced to core blocks through wp-block-styles?

Tags: css, block-editor

[The Gutenberg Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/) mentions that some CSS for WordPress core blocks are applied to the front-end and within the editor by default (and that they cannot be disabled) but there are [more opinionated CSS styles available](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/#default-block-styles) that can be optionally added by adding the following your theme (in one of the PHP files, typically done through functions.php).

```
add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );
```

I'm trying to find a list of these CSS rules added by `wp-block-styles`

I've searched through the Gutenberg repo and the only contents of `wp-block-styles` are the documentation that I linked to above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Gutenberg plugin installed and enabled, the css rules are loaded in
`/plugins/gutenberg/build/block-library/theme.css` ;

If you're just using the block-editor that is in core WordPress, the rules will instead be loaded from:
`wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/theme.css`